# Backtrack algorithm, Stack overflow error, despite heap allocation

Tags: c, recursion, heap-memory, backtracking

I'm currently working on a program that has to solve a 10x10 char maze, for example this one:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
___________________________________________
 1|   +  []   +  []   +  []   +   +   +  []
 2|   +  []   +   +  []   +   +  []  []  []
 3|   +   +  []  []  []   +  []  []   +   +
 4|  []  []  []  []   +   +   +  []  []   +
 5|   +  []   +  []   +  []   +   +   +  []
 6|   +   +   +   +   +   +  []  []   +  []
 7|  []   +   +   +  []  []   +   +   +  []
 8|   +   +   +  []   +   +   +  []  []   +
 9|   +   +   +  []  []   +   +  []  []   +
10|   +  []   +  []   +   +  []   +   +   +
```

Ignore the numbers, they are just coordinates. As for `[]` it's just the way the maze is printed. In actuality wherever there's a `+` then that means path, wherever there's `[]` that means there's an obstacle.

I'm using the backtrack algorithm:

```
void backtrack(int curX, int curY, char(*char_maze)[10], int position)
{
    if (curX < 0 || curY < 0 ||
        curX > 9 || curY > 9) {
        //out of bounds
        return;
    }
    Node tmp;
    tmp.x = curX, tmp.y = curY;
    queue(&head, &tmp);
    position++;
    if (char_maze[curX][curY] == finish) {
        //destination found TODO print path
        printf("route found");
    }
    if (char_maze[curX][curY] == path) {
        char_maze[curX][curY] = visited;
    }
    backtrack(curX, curY - 1, char_maze, position);
    backtrack(curX - 1, curY, char_maze, position);
    backtrack(curX, curY + 1, char_maze, position);
    backtrack(curX + 1, curY, char_maze, position);

    char_maze[curX][curY] = path;
    if (position) {
        del_nth(head, position);
    }
    if (!position) {
        del_first(&head);
    }
    position--;
}
```

The correct route will consist of a linked list, here's a node of that list:

```
typedef struct coords {
    int     x;
    int     y;
    struct coords * next;
}Node;
```

whenever  `backtrack(...)` stumbles over a passable cell, it's supposed to mark it as visited and add it to the list. Adding to the list is done by these 2 functions:

```
void queue(Node ** head, Node * object)
{
    Node * tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); //this is the problematic line
    *tmp = *object;
    Node * last = get_last(*(head));
    if (!last) {
        (*head) = tmp;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        last->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

and

```
Node * get_last(Node * head)
{
    while (1) {
        if (head) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
return head;
}
```

and also under the appropriate conditions `backtrack(...)` should unmark a cell and delete it from the list. Deletion is done using these 2 functions:

```
void del_nth(Node * head, int index)
{
    Node * previous;
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    previous = head;
    head = head->next;
    previous->next = head->next;
    free(head);
}
```

and

```
void del_first(Node ** head)
{
    Node * del = (*head);
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
    free(del);
}
```

`path, visited, finish` and so on are `const char`-s, which represent the cells of the maze.

```
backtrack(...)
```

is called with 2 coordinates set by the user, the maze itself and `position` which is set to `0`.

Now that I explained how the code works, the problem. I've ran this code through the Visual Studio Debugger and I got a `Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00492FFC).` exception on this line

```
Node * tmp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

which is a part of the `queue(...)` function. This doesn't make any sense to me, since `malloc()` allocates on the heap. I'm stumped, I'm out of explanations, I have no idea why this happens. I included all of the code used in the `backtrack(...)` function because the problem may actually be there. It wouldn't be the first time a debugger pointed out a wrong line.
Anyway, many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If a recursive function is giving you a stack overflow, that's because of the stack frame being created for each recursive call; the heap allocation has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You can replace `get_last` with `return NULL` since that's what it does.

Comment: @stark In case of success it was supposed to return a valid pointer to a node. I fixed it, but the problem still remains.

Comment: You still call backtrack even when the cell is already visited.  You should only call when it is still path.

Comment: WOW! A recursive function with 4-recursive calls! Little wonder there is an issue with the recursion going too deep. I suspect you should be guarding each of the recursive calls with a conditional, e.g. `if (...) backtrack (...); else if (...) backtrack (...), ...` and so on. Otherwise, the control will always recurse 4 more times on every call. I haven't worked through your logic here (I'll leave that to you) but suffice it to say, even with 2-recursive calls the logic gets hairy quick -- good luck on this one...

Comment: You have no base case in your recursion. You only stop recursing when you go out of bounds, but nothing stops you from going back and forth between two cells.

Comment: You need to return immediately when the cell has already been visited.

Comment: Unless you're doing this as an iterative algorithm, that linked list management is somewhat pointless. The solution is to (a) have `backtrack` return a meaningful value of 1 (success) or 0 (failure). If the result is successful, push the current coord into the list. TO understand that, think about what values for `curX` and `curY` are in the current activation stack when a successful call to recursive `backtrack` returns. Couple that with most of the comments above and it should be clearer what is broken, and what you should do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You function should return the path it found.  It also should return immediately if the current location is not an open space.  It also should stop whenever a solution is found.

HINT: In most recursive algorithms, the return value is used to stop recursion, so recursive functions usually return something of interest, like the result of the operation.

Example:

```
Node* backtrack(int curX, int curY, char(*char_maze)[10], int position)
{
    Node* node = NULL;

    // return as fast as possible for
    if (curX < 0 || curY < 0 || curX > 9 || curY > 9) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (position > 100)  // 10 * 10 cells.
    {
        // should not reach this point.
        printf("iteration depth exceeded maximum limit!!\n")
        return NULL;
    }

    if (char_maze[curX][curY] == finish) 
    {
        printf("route found");
        node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (node)
        {
            node->x = curX;
            node->y = curY;
            node->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("*** ERROR *** malloc returns NULL (1)!!!\n");
        }

        return node;  // this return point is what triggers the backtrack chaining
                      // of positions
    }
    if (char_maze[curX][curY] != path) // nothing to do
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // mark current location as being worked on.
    char_maze[curX][curY] = visited;

    // now try possible moves, stop looking as soon as a path is found.
    if ((node = backtrack(curX, curY - 1, char_maze, position + 1) != NULL
        || (node = backtrack(curX - 1, curY, char_maze, position + 1) != NULL
        || (node = backtrack(curX, curY + 1, char_maze, position + 1) != NULL
        || (node = backtrack(curX + 1, curY, char_maze, position + 1) != NULL)
    {
        // path found, add current position to the head of the list
        Node* p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (p)
        {
            p->x = curX;
            p->y = curY;
            p->next = node;
            node = p;
        }
        else
        {
            // out of memory, free whatever was allocated before returning.
            printf("*** ERROR *** malloc returns NULL (2)!!!\n");
            while (node)
            {
                p = node->next;
                free(node);
                node = p;
            }
        }
    }

    char_maze[curX][curY] = path;  // clean up.

    return node; // return path found (or not found);
}
```

NOTE: I have not compiled this code, but this should help you complete your program.